# How can I "Show all notification content" for one app, but "Hide sensitive content" for all others?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, privacy

I'm using a timer app, [Multi Timer Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.catfantom.multitimerfree), but it doesn't show the time remaining on the lock screen. Meanwhile, Google's Clock app does. I want to set it to **Show all notification content**, but when I have **Hide sensitive content** turned on system-wide (which is always), **Show all** isn't available. Is there no way to make an exception to the rule?

I considered turning on **Show all notification content** system-wide, but then I'd have to select **Hide sensitive content** for a ton of other apps, which is a hassle.

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219322/115226) indicates that notification sensitivity is set by the dev, so I checked the Multi Timer Free settings (as well as the system notification settings) for anything that could designate the notifications as "public", but didn't see anything.

I'm using Android 9 on a Moto G6. If it's relevant, it's due for an upgrade to Android 10, I just haven't gotten around to re-locking the bootloader yet.

To be verbose, the particular notification class I'm looking at is **Running Timer Notification**.

Comment: Please when talking about a specific app include the link the Google Play Store in the question (or include the app package name) as apps often have different names in different countries and there are often more than one app with the same partial name. Have you contacted the author of the timer app you use? May be this can be better solved in the code of the timer app.

Comment: @Robert Added link, thanks! That's a good point, yeah, I should contact the dev!

Comment: When you open the app page not in Play Store app but in web browser near the end is a contact link of the developer.